# Can't dynamically add controlvalidation to textbox

Tags: asp.net

After several searches on the Internet finally decided to drop a question.
At runtime I want the following to happen.
If you push a button a textbox will be added to the controls and a custom validator must be attached to the textbox and fire.
It does not fire. Why?
Here is my code
Thank you for looking into this.

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    CustomValidator rv2 = new CustomValidator();

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            rv2.ID = "rev2";
            rv2.ErrorMessage = "Not numeric input";
            rv2.ClientValidationFunction = "";
            rv2.ServerValidate += new ServerValidateEventHandler(GetalValidator);
            Controls.Add(rv2);
        }
    }
    protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
        tb1.ID = "tb2";
        tb1.Visible = true;
        tb1.Width = 30;
        this.Controls.Add(tb1);`enter code here`
        rv2.EnableClientScript = false;
        rv2.ControlToValidate = "tb2";
    }
    private bool IsNumber(string someText)
    {
        int number;
        bool result = Int32.TryParse(someText, out number);
        return result;
    }
    protected void GetalValidator(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = IsNumber(args.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is part of code thorugh which you can add validation on your dynamically created control.

```
    TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
    tb1.ID = "tb2";
    tb1.Visible = true;
    tb1.Width = 30;

    RequiredFieldValidator regfv = new RequiredFieldValidator();
    regfv.ID = "regfv";
    regfv.ControlToValidate = tb1.ID;
    regfv.ErrorMessage = "My Error";

   this.Controls.Add(tb1);
   this.Controls.Add(regfv);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your suggestion will work no doubt, but in the end I want to attach one CustomValidator to several textboxes which are created at runtime. This I can't get to work

Comment: @MuradMaas: show your complete code, which you have tried so far, including your custom validator.

Comment: Hallo Amit, I already send the complete code including the dynamically created custum validator